# CSS Modulesで@importを含んだCSSのクラス名が取得できない

Tags: webpack

webpackのcss-loaderを使ったCSS Modulesで `@import` したファイルのクラス名が取得できません。以下に最小と思われる再現コードを掲載します。

### 再現コード

#### test.html

```html
<script src="dist/main.js"></script>
```

JavaScriptを実行するのが目的です。

#### src/index.js

```js
const styles = require('./index.css');
console.log('styles', styles);
console.log('index', styles.locals.testindex);
console.log('import', styles.locals.testimport);
```

デバッグが目的です。最後の `styles.locals.testimport` が `undefined` になって困っています（後述）。

#### src/index.css

```css
@import 'import.css';

.testindex {
  color: red;
}
```

#### src/import.css

```css
.testimport {
  background: blue;
}
```

#### webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              import: true,
              modules: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

### 再現方法

```
npm i -D css-loader webpack webpack-cli
npx webpack --mode production
open test.html
```

#### consoleへの出力

```
styles {
  0: [3, "._10aNScd5VABi2Vi1Zunpbc {↵  background: blue;↵}↵", ""],
  1: [2, "._2ppZfX3K2LiFyomekB0B7T {↵  color: red;↵}↵", ""],
  locals: {
    testindex: "_2ppZfX3K2LiFyomekB0B7T"
  }
}
index _2ppZfX3K2LiFyomekB0B7T
import undefined
```

### やりたいこと

`@import` 先のクラスである `testimport` が `_10aNScd5VABi2Vi1Zunpbc` に置き換わっているのが確認できるのですが、これを `styles.locals.testimport` で取得したいです。

オプションもしくはwebpackプラグインの追加で解決する方法があれば嬉しいです。仕様でしたら記載されているところを教えていただけると助かります。